# Retrieving Image from Google Places API in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, google-places-api

In one fragment, I have implemented a Google PlaceAutoCompleteFragment. When a place is selected, I'd like to upload an image of that place to a Parse server, so I've been following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/photos).

In OnCreateView(), I've initialized the GeoDataClient mGeoDataClient using

```
mGeoDataClient = Places.getGeoDataClient(getActivity());
```

I'm passing the correct placeId into the following method, and the debugger says that photoMetadataResponse is *zzu@6303* (which I assume is okay?). It seems like onComplete is never being executed, and bitmapArray has size 0 at the end so *bitmap* is returned as null.

```
       // Request photos and metadata for the specified place.
private Bitmap getPhotos(String placeId) {
    final ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    final Task<PlacePhotoMetadataResponse> photoMetadataResponse = mGeoDataClient.getPlacePhotos(placeId);
    photoMetadataResponse.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<PlacePhotoMetadataResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<PlacePhotoMetadataResponse> task) {
            // Get the list of photos.
            PlacePhotoMetadataResponse photos = task.getResult();
            // Get the PlacePhotoMetadataBuffer (metadata for all of the photos).
            PlacePhotoMetadataBuffer photoMetadataBuffer = photos.getPhotoMetadata();
            // Get the first photo in the list.
            PlacePhotoMetadata photoMetadata = photoMetadataBuffer.get(0);
            // Get the attribution text.
            CharSequence attribution = photoMetadata.getAttributions();
            // Get a full-size bitmap for the photo.
            Task<PlacePhotoResponse> photoResponse = mGeoDataClient.getPhoto(photoMetadata);
            photoResponse.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<PlacePhotoResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<PlacePhotoResponse> task) {
                    PlacePhotoResponse photo = task.getResult();
                    Bitmap bitmap = photo.getBitmap();
                    bitmapArray.add(bitmap); // Add a bitmap
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return bitmapArray.get(0);
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are returning `bitmapArray.get(0);` before the onCompleteListener is complete. You should set a variable `bitmapArray` at the top of your fragment and add bitmap to the ArrayList once the photo completeListener is complete.

```
public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {

//Google places
protected GeoDataClient mGeoDataClient;

//vars
prvivate ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, container, false);

    mGeoDataClient = Places.getGeoDataClient(ExampleFragment.this, null);

    return view;
}

// Request photos and metadata for the specified place.
private void getPhotos(String placeId) {
    final Task<PlacePhotoMetadataResponse> photoMetadataResponse = mGeoDataClient.getPlacePhotos(placeId);
    photoMetadataResponse.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<PlacePhotoMetadataResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<PlacePhotoMetadataResponse> task) {
            // Get the list of photos.
            PlacePhotoMetadataResponse photos = task.getResult();
            // Get the PlacePhotoMetadataBuffer (metadata for all of the photos).
            PlacePhotoMetadataBuffer photoMetadataBuffer = photos.getPhotoMetadata();
            // Get the first photo in the list.
            PlacePhotoMetadata photoMetadata = photoMetadataBuffer.get(0);
            // Get the attribution text.
            CharSequence attribution = photoMetadata.getAttributions();
            // Get a full-size bitmap for the photo.
            Task<PlacePhotoResponse> photoResponse = mGeoDataClient.getPhoto(photoMetadata);
            photoResponse.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<PlacePhotoResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<PlacePhotoResponse> task) {
                    PlacePhotoResponse photo = task.getResult();
                    Bitmap bitmap = photo.getBitmap();
                    bitmapArray.add(bitmap); // Add a bitmap to array
                    //handle the new bitmap here

                }
            });
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I implemented this and called getPhotos(id);
                            bitmap = bitmapArray.get(0); in onPlaceSelected but I'm still getting 0 for the size of bitmapArray and a null pointer exception for bitmap.

Comment: If you are updating an imageView or uploading the bitmap to a server, you should call that function inside the `photoResponse.addOnCompleteListener` so that the function handling the bitmap isn't called until the bitmap task is complete.